# Cannot connect to HDMI Panasonic TV after Ventura upgrade

Tags: display, upgrade, hdmi, ventura

I have been grappling with this for some time. Since I upgraded to Ventura I am unable to mirror my MacBook Pro 2018 display on Panasonic TV with HDMI cable. Prior to upgrade it was connecting fine.

Annoyingly, my wife has a MacBook Air 2020 (M1 chip) that connects to the same TV using the same HDMI cable with no problems whatsoever. I have tried. I can only assume that it is a glitch in the upgrade process, but cannot find a way to fix it.

I have tried various combinations of unplugging and restarting, detecting displays and using a new cable and new HDMI/USBC adapter (But why this should be of any use when old cable & adapter works perfectly with the newer MacBook is beyond me)

Any ideas will be gratefully received.

Comment: What version Ventura?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

macOS 13 Ventura BREAKS Panasonic TV connection via HDMI
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254775822

Comment: Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.